# Free API Which return DATE TIME details by passing latitude and longitude of place

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone application, i have a requirement to get a place details like DATE, TIME , TIMEZONE etc.. by just passing latitude and longitude details of that place

please suggest any other way to get those details or any free API which returns this details.

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: The sun rises for free everyday, guaranteed.  Unlike the many available web services, they suddenly hit you with a big charge when you use them often enough and came to depend on one.  You'll need to go shopping yourself, nobody knows your budget and app prospects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) web services. You'd probably want the [time zone API](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone). Or they allow you to download the data yourself, so you could ship a reduced subset of the data provided with your app.

Note that the time zone ID provided by GeoNames (or most other web services) would be the [TZDB time zone ID](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). You can use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library to get more details of that time zone, such as the offset from UTC at a particular point in time (e.g. now).